# How to write Geospatial query in MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb, geolocation

I'm working on MongoDB using Java. In that I have a table where I had stored the location coordinates. I have to get the nearest location in the list. I have followed  [this site](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes) and tried this.

```
db.location.find({ loc: { $near : { $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [80.23,13.1112] }, $minDistance: 0, $maxDistance:1000 } } } )
```

This is working good but I don't have any idea about the right syntax in Mongo Java, I need to do the same in Java code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code replicates the above mongo shell query in Java:

```
BasicDBObject criteria = new BasicDBObject("$near", new double[] { -80.23, 13.1112 });
criteria.put("$maxDistance", 1000);

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("loc", criteria);

List<DBObject> obj = getCollection("location").find(query).toArray()
```